# Symfony inject parameter to form from buildForm

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony <4 and I have an issue with a form using an other form in a Many-To-Many relation with parameter.

You will find below my FeatureForm:

```
            ->add('tags',CollectionType::class,
            array(
                'entry_type' =>TagFeatureType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'data' => $datas,
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'label' => false,
                )
            )
        )
```

Now my TagFeatureType:

```
            ->add('tag', EntityType::class,
            array(
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Tag',
                'query_builder' => function(TagRepository $tr){
                    return $tr->findObjectNotMine();
                }
            )
        )
```

I would like to inject a parameter into findOBjectNotMine but I cannot pass parameter from controller because the TagFeatureType is created by FeatureForm. Inside the buildForm function I cannot pass any extra parameter.

I see 2 possibilites, 1st I modify default options to allow an extra option, but it's a bit disgusting. 2nd, I could use session parameter and inject session service inside the constructor... But it looks like more a workaround than a proper way...

Do you know an elegant way to inject parameter to a form from buildForm function inside FormType?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you need to pass container-known parameters to custom form type, you can go the way you attempted above (obviously via parameter injection). However, if you want to pass data from controller down to form type, you can pass it via `$options` (last) argument (in `buildForm`):

<kbd>FeatureForm</kbd>

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

    // ....

    $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array (
           'entry_type' => TagFeatureType::class,
           'allow_add' => true,
           'allow_delete' => true,
           'data' => $datas,
           'entry_options' => array(
               'label' => false,
               'some_custom_param' => $options['some_custom_param']
           )
       )
    );

    // ....
 }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Task::class
    ));
    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'some_custom_param'
    ));
}
```

And then, in `TagFeatureType` should have configured options:

<kbd>TagFeatureType</kbd>

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'some_custom_param'
    ));
}
```

And then finally, include it inside of `buildForm`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

    // ....
    $someCustomParam = $options['some_custom_param'];

    // .... 

    $builder->add('tag', EntityType::class, array(
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Tag',
        'query_builder' => function(TagRepository $tr) use ($someCustomParam) 
        {
            return $tr->findObjectNotMine($someCustomParam);
        }
    );

    // ....
}
```

Obvious downside of this would be a need for all the forms in path to have `setRequired` or `setDefault`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah it works fine. I didnt know I could change extra options for only one form. I set your post as answer, could you edit your answer because you access parameter through $this, it doesnt work in Symfony 2.8 (maybe it does later?). I have to access through $options. After that your answer will be perfect! You even updated the closure ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your TagFeatureType you can just pass in the argument via constructor injection:

```
class TagFeatureType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tagRepository;

    public function __construct(TagRepository $tagRepository)
    {
        $this->tagRepository = $tagRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $tr = $this->tagRepository;
        // ...
        ->add('tag', EntityType::class,
            array(
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Tag',
                'query_builder' => function(TagRepository $tr){
                    return $tr->findObjectNotMine();
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

There is a [DependencyInjectionExtension form extension](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionExtension.php) that will check if the form type is registered in the service container and then inject it, instead of creating a new instance. This should make sure that the tag repository exists.